# Unwrapping planar rectangle doesnt result in same rectangle in uv editor

Tags: uv

I have a planar mesh, but when i unwrap it, it gets distorted. So i gave up and marked every single edge as seam. But even unwrapping one single planar face doesnt result in the same object in the uv editor. In the image i marked the corresponding vertices in 3D View (top) and UV Editor (bottom). [image: Vertex distortion when unwrapping]

There are many faces within my mesh with this problem, so correcting this manually is no option.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That face is not a quad, try to select everything and remove doubles and then unwrap again.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to maintain the proportions of a planar mesh, set the view from top ortho, then press U "project from view" option.

Comment: That helped. Thank you very much. You saved me a lot of time!